# How to compute F-statistics for each features of regression models in glmnet?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, f-statistic

I have learned lot's of Lasso regression models(20000) using glmnet.
I need to compute somehow test statistics for each features of models. like F-statistics,...

Can I do this using bootstrapping ? if yes, how is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean you've fit a model to 20000 _variables_ using the lasso, or 20000 _models_? I can't imagine a situation where it's the latter....

Comment: no, I mean how to compute F-statistics for each features of regression model.